# Knockout Data not Rendering

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sinatra

I'm building a simple web app using sinatra and knockout.js. My basic structure is a model on the backend that only returns json, and rendering everything client side using knockout. But my data isn't rendering, even when I pre-populate the array.

Here's part of app.rb:

```
    get "/" do
        content_type 'html'
        erb :index
    end
    get "/topics" do
        @topics = Topic.all
        @topics.to_json
    end
    get "/topics/:id" do
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
        @topic.to_json
    end
    post "/topics/new" do
        @topic = Topic.new(name: params[:name],
                           description: params[:description])
        @topic.created_at = DateTime.now

    end
```

And my database:

```
    APP_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
    DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite:///#{APP_ROOT}/db.sqlite3")
    class Topic
        include DataMapper::Resource
        property :id, Serial
        property :name, Text
        property :description, Text
        property :created_at,        DateTime
        property :updated_at,        DateTime
    end
    DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

My Javascript file:

```
function Topic(data){
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.description = ko.observable(data.description);
    this.created_at = ko.observable(data.created_at);
    this.updated_at = ko.observable(data.updated_at);
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
}
function TopicViewModel(){
    var that = this;
    that.topics = ko.observableArray([{name: "hello",description: "hi"}]);
    $.getJSON("/topics",function(raw){
        var topics = $.map(raw, function(item){return new Topic(item)});
        that.topics(topics);
    });
    that.newTopic = ko.observable();
        that.addTopic = function(){
            var newTopic = new Topic({name: "", description: ""});
            $.getJSON("date", function(data){
                newTopic.created_at(data.date);
                newTopic.updated_at(data.date);
                that.topics.push(newTopic);
                that.saveTopic(newTopic);
            });
        };
    that.saveTopic = function(topic){
        var t= ko.toJS(topic);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:4567/topics/new",
            type: "POST",
            data: t
        }).done(function(data){
            topic.id(data.topic.id);
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new TopicViewModel());
```

Finally, my html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css">
    <title>Topics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <section id="create">
                <h2>New Topic</h2>
                <form id="addTopic" data-bind="submit: addTopic">
                    <input data-bind="value: name"/>
                    <input data-bind="value: description"/>
                    <button type="submit">Create Topic</button>
                </form>
            </section>
            <section id="topics">
                <!-- ko foreach: topics -->
                   <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: created_at"></td>
                   <td data-bind="text: updated_at"></td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </section>
            <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/knockout.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Why isn't this rendering?

Comment: Do the Sinatra routes return data? (e.g. from a cURL request or just a  browswer) By the way, if you're not going to render using Sinatra views then there's no point to using instance variables.

Comment: Yes, when I prepopulate that db on the backend they return data.

Comment: Does the done method fire in Your ajax request? What's the data that it receives? (use console.log(data); in done method). It might be that You try to perform crossdomain request and hasn't set appropriate crossdomain headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your html is not valid. You are trying to render `td`s inside a `section`...

Change your `td` to `span` (or `div` ) and it should work fine:

```
<section id="topics">
  <!-- ko foreach: topics -->
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: created_at"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: updated_at"></span>
   <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

Or build a correct `table` (Knockout cannot figure it out that you want a table and magically render it for you)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>created_at</th>
            <th>updated_at</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: topics -->
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: created_at"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: updated_at"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Comment: Html is sure invalid but as far as I know, tds in a section should render themselves incorrectly. But they should be there anyway.

Comment: But Knockout will be confused when the HTML is invalid and sometimes it result nothing being generated... Have you tried with span's or with table? Is it working now for you?